# Grab decimals with regex

Tags: regex

Good morning,

I'm new at working with regex and need something what I can not find.

I've an expression: 
]C193123456789.123
To get the first digits before the dot I know 
`^93[data.*]\.` = 123456789
]C1 is my leading Identifier so it doesn't matter.

My question now is, how can I get the digits after the dot? = 123

Thanks

Comment: So, is the input `]C193123456789.123` ? Your example isn't very clear :/

Comment: May be `\.[data.*]$`?

Comment: How did you get digits before dot?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I do is a barcode parsing. in the barcode I have a leading identifier that is ]C1 and I have an identifier for EAN128 that is 93. The barcode has 2 differnt information in "item number (123456789)" and "size (123). the decimal dot is the point in between of this. The item number I can extract but dot the size. that is my problem.

Comment: If the leading identifier is fixed (i.e. ]C1), isn't this going to solved your question: `]C1\d+\.(\d+)`? or try `[^.]+\.(\d+)`.

Answer (score 0):

I you only want those digits and no other :

```
(?<=\.)\d+
```

This returns as much digits preceded by a litteral `.` as possible.

If you want to capture both suits of digits, you can use grouping :

```
(\d+)\.(\d+)
```

Where the units can be retrieved with `\1` and the decimal with `\2`.

Comment: I tried this, but it is not working. I have the identifier in 2 different fields and it looks like, when I end my expression '^93[?Data.*]' with \. it will stop at the dot and not go further to my next expression.

Comment: I don't see what the `^93[?Data.*]` regex is supposed to do here... supposing this is what you use to retrieve the `]C193123456789.123` string, you could try `^93[?Data.*]\.(\d+)` and retrieve the first capturing group. Btw I'm almost sure `[?Data.*]` is not doing what you think it does : it's currently matching any of the `?` , `D`, `a`, `t`, `.`, `*` characters

Comment: Sorry I accidently said [ instead of ( here in the text. it is ^93(?Data.*)\. If I do ^93(?Data.*)\.(\d+) it gives me nothing in my fields. It says matching, but nothing is there.

Comment: what about `^93(?Data.*).*\.(\d+)` ?

Comment: The (\d) will strip out all data on the variable. If I not use this it will show me in my variable1 123456789 but I'm not able to get the 123 in my second variable :( maybe one more idea?

Comment: I don't get what's your problem. See theses examples : [matching only the last digits with lookbehind](https://regex101.com/r/cG8hW6/1) (i actually had an error with my answer, I updated it) - [getting the digits in groups](https://regex101.com/r/yT3cE1/1) - [getting only the decimals in the first group](https://regex101.com/r/yT3cE1/2)

Comment: @maccloud to be specific your problem seems to be relative to the tool you use to execute regular expressions. Could you tell me which is it?

Comment: Sorry for not coming back yesterday to you: I found a way to fix the problem. It is a company internal tool to do a barcode parsing for scanned barcodes. The solution for it is: '^93(?Data[^DELIM]{1,255})\.' and in the next line for the second value '(?Data[^DELIM]{1,255}'. The first line will add all data before the dot to the first value and the second line will add all data after the dot to the second value. So it is split and I ca bring the data to the ERP system. Thanks a lot for your help.