# Regex - grab decimal(12,2)

Tags: regex

I am using a regex to display a tooltip when the user's pattern doesn`t match desired pattern.

The RULES are:

1. Must match 1 to 10 digits or less. Ex: 1234567890 or 0 or 123... . 0 digits is empty. Not allowed.
2. Must match max 10 digits or less and a dot. Ex: 1234567890. or 12. or 1. or 0.
3. Must match max 10 digits or less and a dot. and 1 or 2 digits after dot. Ex: 1.1 or 1234.23 or 1234567890.1 or 1234567890.12 OR .1 OR .21
4. Only `.` is not allowed.

So far I have this pattern `^\d{0,8}?(\.)?(\d{1,2})?$`  [Link](https://regex101.com/r/jG3uK7/1)  but I can not realize how to match all conditions at once.

This pattern can not match `1234567890.12` (it should). And it is matching the dot alone `.`(should not).
Some post I found do not solve the issue [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36737680/grab-decimals-with-regex).

What am I missing?

---

The complete function

```
$('.validation').bind({             

             keyup:function(){

                   //var objectEvent=$(this);
                   var objectId=$(this).attr("id");
                   var objectEvent=$("#"+objectId);


                   if(objectId=="txt_Attend"){
                          var ck_input = /^\d+$/;
                          var msg="Oops! Only numbers 1-9 are allowed";
                          var extraVal ="0";
                   }
                   else if(objectId=="txt_SalesYTD"||objectId=="txt_PrevSales"){//alert(objectId);
                          //var ck_input = /^\d{0,10}((\.\d{1,2})?|(?<=\d)\.)$/;
                          var ck_input = /^(?!\.$)\d{0,10}(?:\.(?:\d\d?)?)?$/;
                          var msg="Enter a valid value. Ex: 123.35";
                          var extraVal ="";
                          //alert(ck_input);
                   }
                   var input = $.trim(objectEvent.val());
                   var validationTest =ck_input.test(input);   
                   //alert(validationTest);
                   //QTY field Validation --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                   if(!validationTest||input===extraVal){//If not match ck_input
                         //alert("algo errado"+input);                                                        
                                 objectEvent.val('');//Clear input field
                                 objectEvent.attr('data-original-title',msg);
                                 objectEvent.tooltip('show');
                                 setTimeout( function(){ 
                                       objectEvent.tooltip('hide');
                                       objectEvent.removeAttr('title');
                                       objectEvent.removeAttr('data-original-title'); 
                                   }  , 2500 ); //Wait 2,5 seconds     
                   }                   
                   else{//If validation match ck_input


                         objectEvent.tooltip('hide');
                                            objectEvent.removeAttr('title');
                                            objectEvent.removeAttr('data-original-title');   

                   }//End of else if(!validationTest||input==='0'){
             }//Fim keyUp
    });//End of $('.validation').bind({
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the first rage to `{0,10}` and put the dot and second numbers in same capture group with an optional dot that must be precede by a digit:

```
^\d{0,10}((\.\d{1,2})?|(?<=\d)\.)$
```

See demo: https://regex101.com/r/jG3uK7/4

Comment: Hi Kasramvd your pattern is not matching `.1` and `.12`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
^(?!\.$)\d{0,10}(?:\.(?:\d\d?)?)?$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yX1kF6/4)**

Comment: Hi Rock, Rule 3. Your patter is not matching `.1` and `.12`

Comment: @zwitterion see modified regex

Comment: Hi Rock your patter is matching the dot. Rule 4. Not allowed. Kasramvd found the good pattern

Comment: @zwitterion see the updated regex..i think it should suffice all condition now

Comment: @zwitterion alternation takes more step..this solution will be more efficient than accepted one

Comment: I gave you plus 1. I dont know why your pattern works in my code. Kasramvd's code, dont. But his pattern replies the question.

Comment: @zwitterion what's the language you are using?